# Easiest and most efficient way to shade corner of UIImageview

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiimageview

My app has tons of images for different cities around the world, the problem is, some of these images don't work too well with the white labels in the bottom right corner, I was wondering if there was some sort of way to maybe blur or shade the corner and only that corner, to make all the images look nice with the labels. 
Example: (yes I know the labels don't match the cities, I haven't imported all the cities in yet.)

[image]

That one might look fine.

[image]

But this one could use some shading.
Anyway for me to make the UIImageView have some sort of blur/masking shade effect on the right bottom corner to make all the images look good without having to photoshop hundreds of individual photos?
Thanks so much guys.

Comment: I'd suggest adding shadow to your text?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CILinearGradient](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004346) to get a vignetting effect in one corner only:

[image]

```
- (CIImage*) processPhoto:(CIImage*)image {
    CGFloat width = [image extent].size.width;
    CGFloat height = [image extent].size.height;

    CIFilter* gradient = [CIFilter filterWithName:CILinearGradient];

    [gradient setValue:
        [CIVector vectorWithX:width*0.75 Y:height*0.5]
                forKey:@"inputPoint0"];

    [gradient setValue:
        [CIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:0]
                forKey:@"inputColor0"];

    [gradient setValue:
        [CIVector vectorWithX:width*0.85 Y:0]
                forKey:@"inputPoint1"];

    [gradient setValue:
        [CIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.7]
                forKey:@"inputColor1"];

    CIImage* croppedImage =
        [gradient.outputImage imageByCroppingToRect:[image extent]];

    CIFilter* composite = [CIFilter filterWithName:CIHardLightBlendMode];
    [composite setValue:croppedImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [composite setValue:image forKey:kCIInputBackgroundImageKey];
    return composite.outputImage;
}
```

You might want to tweak the endpoints and gradient a bit more for an optimal result.

Alternatively, if you'd rather go for a squared-off look you could just stick a UIView between the text and the image with a black background and ~0.4 opacity:

[image]

Design-wise, I think that's a better approach but the code is not so interesting!

Answer (score -1):

You could change the CALayer property of images ..which is very efficient and powerful
Try this:

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

view.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor COLOR] CGColor];

view.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;

view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;